# Extract Keywords From title Text String in array With PHP

Tags: php

i am trying to extract Keywords from post title

i did this

```
function extractKeyWords($string) {
  mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
  $stopwords = array();
  $string = preg_replace('/[\pP]/u', '', trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/iu', '', mb_strtolower($string))));
  $matchWords = array_filter(explode(' ',$string) , function ($item) use ($stopwords) { return !($item == '' || in_array($item, $stopwords) || mb_strlen($item) <= 2 || is_numeric($item));});
  $wordCountArr = array_count_values($matchWords);
  arsort($wordCountArr);
  return array_keys(array_slice($wordCountArr, 0, 10));
}
```

in array

```
$data = [
    'title'            => $title,
    'meta.keywords' => implode(',', extractKeyWords($title)),
 ];
        return view('single.php', $data);
```

but does not work "blank page"

Comment: hi there OsamahM - many thanks for sharing this with us. The result you get is a `blank` page?! i for one like your ideas with the regex

Comment: thanks  ,yes blank page still trying to fix it